# Using Python to change Callout Outline color in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, python-parser, callout

I am using ArcGIS pro to create some maps. There is a polyline feature layer where all of the important data comes from, which is determined by the fields "Direction" with domain of North, East, South, West; and the field "Value" which needs to be displayed. I am using a Callout to place the value over each line.

What I need is for both the text and the outline of the callout to be the same color as the polyline. I have successfully made the text color change, but I cannot seem to get the outline of the callout to change and I can't find any documentation on the topic. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def FindLabel ( [Value], [Direction] ):
    if [Value] is None:
        return ""
    elif [Direction] == 'South':
        return "<CLR red='56' green='168'><FNT size = '11'>" + [Value] + "%" + "</FNT></CLR>"
    elif [Direction] == 'North':
        return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '11'>" + [Value] + "%" + "</FNT></CLR>"
    elif [Direction] == 'West':
        return "<CLR red='255' green='170'><FNT size = '11'>" + [Value] + "%" + "</FNT></CLR>"
    elif [Direction] == 'East':
        return "<CLR green= '169' blue='230'><FNT size = '11'>" + [Value] + "%" + "</FNT></CLR>"
    else:
        return "Directional Value not Properly Set"
```

I will also include photos to show what my callout looks like and what the desired callout will look like.

My Callout:

[image: My current callout]

My desired Callout:

[image: what I want my callout to look like]

Comment: Slightly related: Your labels are appearing over the road names (presumably a label class), Esri allows you to weight labels to avoid overlapping https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/weight-labels-and-features.htm. If you can, use the Maplex label engine, it is far superior to the Esri standard label engine... just a couple of tips to make your output tidier with a minimum of effort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can link the call out edge to an attribute.  What you can do it create different classes of labels where you have set the call out edge to your desired colour.  So in your case you create a new class of label for each of your direction values with their custom colours.

You create a new label class by simply click on the down arrow in the class box as shown below:

[image: label class]

If you apply a SQL Query to the class to filter by direction you can do away with your python code completely as you would set the colour of the text.